# Auto image slider with swipe to full size

Tags: android

I was wondering if you could help me with something. I'm trying to build an image slideshow with a swipe/click to full size feature. Similar to Expedia's slideshow (see Youtube for video example of what i want to accomplish).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu45DrvqrVg&feature=youtu.be&t=2m10s

As of now i'm using daimajia's AndroidImageSlider pulling images with JSON. I'm not sure if such a feature is supported by this library. I also thought about possibly using a viewpager/viewflipper but as i am quite new to java i'm not sure how i am going to implement the swipe down/click to full size image.

Breakdown:
Auto image slider with given height and swipe/click to full size (see Expedia)

I would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction or provide me with a some sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find out the solution? I also want to have a image slider likes this